# Seiberg-Witten Theory and the Kähler manifold

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, supersymmetry, seiberg-witten-theory

Starting from the Kähler potential

$$\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{4\pi} Im(\int d^{4}\theta tr(\Phi^{\dagger}e^{2V}\Phi),$$

How do we integrate out to get the following Lagrangian:

$$\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{4\pi} Im(\int d^{4}\theta F'(A)\bar{A}+\int d^{2}\theta \frac{1}{2}F''(A)W^{\alpha}W_{\alpha})~?$$

Which we see in Seiberg-Witten theory. And how do I then obtain the metric of the Kähler manifold?

$$ds^{2}= \frac{1}{4\pi} Im(da_{D} da^{*}).$$

These results seem to appear in lecture notes/ reviews covering Seiberg-Witten theory all the time but I am unsure of where they come from/ how to derive them given just an $\mathcal{N}=2$ SYM theory with an $SU(2)$ gauge group. As seen in https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9407087 Equations 2.7 - 2.10.